# Perform task when not online & timing (No cron jobs please) (Simple)

Tags: php, mysql, logic, task

I have the following code

```
  $timeNow = time();
    $timeExpire = $timeNow - 15;
    $con->query("UPDATE players SET Time='".$timeNow."', TimeExpire='".$timeExpire."' WHERE Username='". $_SESSION['Username']."'");
    $User = $con->query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE Username='".$_SESSION['Username']."'");
    $UserInfo = $User->fetch_object();

    if($UserInfo->Wood == "") {
    $con->query("UPDATE players SET Wood='0'");
    } elseif($UserInfo->Stone == "") {
    $con->query("UPDATE players SET Stone='0'");
    } elseif($UserInfo->Gold == "") {
    $con->query("UPDATE players SET Gold='0'");
    }
    if((time() - 15) >= $UserInfo->TimeExpire) {

    $getAmount = (time() - $UserInfo->TimeExpire);
    $con->query("UPDATE players SET Wood=Wood+$getAmount, Stone=Stone+$getAmount, Gold=Gold+$getAmount WHERE Username='". $_SESSION['Username']."'");


}
```

I have a couple of questions:

- How can I make it so that the user can only receive Wood, Stone and
  Gold every 10 seconds (otherwise they can just refresh the page)
- How can I calculate how many expirations were there? For example if
  they are logged out for 2 hours and then log in back they get the
  money the would get if they were online 2 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need these queries to execute all the time.
Just create a column in your players table to record the last time they received resources, something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE players ADD LastTimeReceivedResources INT(5)
```

When a users loads a page, you check this field to see how much time has passed without them getting resources:

```
$wood_per_10_seconds = 15;
$last_time_received_resources = ...; // Get from players table
$time_now = time();
$added_wood = floor(($time_now-$last_time_received_resources)/10) * $wood_per_10_seconds;

$con->query("UPDATE players SET Wood=Wood+$added_wood WHERE Username='".$_SESSION['Username']."'");
```

After this you save the current time into the LastTimeReceivedResources field:

```
if ($added_wood>0) $con->query("UPDATE players SET LastTimeReceivedResources=$time_now WHERE Username='".$_SESSION['Username']."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the last time a refresh was done. Retrieve the last refresh, calculate seconds since then.

```
$date = new DateTime( '2013-09-10 18:07:13' );
$date2 = new DateTime( '2013-09-11 18:11:08' );

$diff = $date2->getTimestamp() - $date->getTimestamp();
```

Though i do think a good old global cron would be the way to go, personally.

Comment: Your user table should just have the need for only one column 'lastResourceRefresh'. Populate this anytime with the current timestamp when you give them resources. When you run the operation to give them resources (login, refresh, etc) grab that date and use the code I posted to detemine if and how many resources they should get, and update the date in the table again. Very simple.